# Jsrsasign. How to verify the signature on the server?

Tags: javascript, ssl, openssl, sign

Good morning.

I need to generate a certificate on a mobile device for later send to the server.

The intention is to sign some unique feature of the device and check it on the server.

I use the following method

```
// Create cert

var publickey="";
publickey=publickey+"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
publickey=publickey+"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQD2Alder/8ByIu+565IRZS+xB6t";
publickey=publickey+"hJkmlwNy7wMRTX7YysHC9S75wR/FLWFdsjMP+3TElvxsck+A3emsd2TYcJr0s4p7";
publickey=publickey+"5vP8k3Cap39mTXVNLRyaiFZt4ViJTYhsNWtAfS8t8T56FWPxy1prilR0AQHp+Qj5";
publickey=publickey+"VKdp8Rwfik4GrHOGWQIDAQAB\n";
publickey=publickey+"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

var privatekey="";      
privatekey=privatekey+"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
privatekey=privatekey+"MIICXAIBAAKBgQD2Alder/8ByIu+565IRZS+xB6thJkmlwNy7wMRTX7YysHC9S75";
privatekey=privatekey+"wR/FLWFdsjMP+3TElvxsck+A3emsd2TYcJr0s4p75vP8k3Cap39mTXVNLRyaiFZt";
privatekey=privatekey+"4ViJTYhsNWtAfS8t8T56FWPxy1prilR0AQHp+Qj5VKdp8Rwfik4GrHOGWQIDAQAB";
privatekey=privatekey+"AoGAbhYIIPAi7hpfJrOoUuEIOgGrNLzEh/dF7NW2CrUiEUNSR7rOJaddXy/6hSIs";
privatekey=privatekey+"JXfB/gMOvDy/BQzI94uKDiz9uahMcuADhpUJBpDQMP5B1xMwVAxm8MLHEi86Bn3T";
privatekey=privatekey+"W/yaTsa7SYlnMu0TJl1xQFeB9cQS4qZIUgGR44774yIM/V0CQQD92Xz9ojSgcT4m";
privatekey=privatekey+"Hz1ua4jNTBtUPT+Buxr3IZraaXVYKIUiW1dFXiD6BZ0PVFdA8yBTvltoidjv/5zv";
privatekey=privatekey+"7Pm6alHDAkEA+BfZkqBvLXFQtHgxVaj+JMIXei9TWkhtQt9no1IWAZd/vvBDJelE";
privatekey=privatekey+"utOsG824g/I2+mLnYHDFLfH7CBeMz4mJswJAXbRq7zVxN8iVqHzfsGMBnMb7T51M";
privatekey=privatekey+"VBc9XPyKrRVAu8o5WvVcwb59bc2krIP1sYQN6tvZ4j0AV5eD1w0jIi0dAQJBAKQ7";
privatekey=privatekey+"ZZRjEDYM5VgSmNYT4OmEcvY3jf4eI/Y43eqH1HmJSM+lTU4zdYQXy788GAGAvlRS";
privatekey=privatekey+"VMjK3jzkC0H4FQbuDXECQDaFTYpdYkUDeGPX4YTEPBbwMyJygjRDD3X067bgAJ/+";
privatekey=privatekey+"z9pgsAsHhle6aQv09c0t2j+6LPVeFpSvd2u8g9+9U0o=\n";
privatekey=privatekey+"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

var rsa = new RSAKey();
rsa.readPrivateKeyFromPEMString(privatekey);

var tbsc = new KJUR.asn1.x509.TBSCertificate();
tbsc.setSerialNumberByParam({'int': 9999});
tbsc.setSignatureAlgByParam({'name': 'SHA256withRSA'});
tbsc.setIssuerByParam({'str': '/C=ES/O=MOBILE-CA'});  
tbsc.setNotBeforeByParam({'str': '130501235959Z'});
tbsc.setNotAfterByParam({'str': '230501235959Z'});
tbsc.setSubjectByParam({'str': '/C=ES/CN=SOME'});  
tbsc.setSubjectPublicKeyByParam({'rsapem': publickey});
var cert = new KJUR.asn1.x509.Certificate({'tbscertobj': tbsc,
                                            'prvkeyobj': rsa
});
cert.sign(); 

var x509toServer=cert.getPEMString(); // Send to server

// Generate sign
var xig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withRSA"});
xig.init(rsa);
xig.updateString("zzzzttttzzzz");
var xSigVal = xig.sign();                       
console.log('Sign: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
console.log(xSigVal);
console.log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');

// Verify sign
var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withRSA"});
sig.initVerifyByCertificatePEM(cert.getPEMString()); // signer's certificate
sig.updateString(me.getApplication().device_uid);
var isValid = sig.verify(xSigVal)  
if (isValid) {
    console.log("valid");
} else {
    console.log("invalid");
}
```

The above code works perfectly, and shows me that the signature is valid.

The certificate server receives the message (zzzzttttzzzz) and signed (variable xSigVal).

and the next files are generated

device.cer with

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

message.txt with

```
zzzzttttzzzz
```

firma.sign with

cbfbaa6f099fafdb9d892a9d2ea7378a66685e429f77e24241e2e5531db9c020829de125467a891504aaa42b174b0d47d6c83e8234fe32918900ba219cd75b024fa21c241a8c8463ffe629a8e3cf094014cb19a70734db8a0f7b856fb60f4cf9425af8982a9404bfaa8a9e09d742160bca588c4464c17467ef2de69d1b0c46d0

The information returned by the certificate on server is

```
openssl x509 -in c/device.cer -noout -text

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 9999 (0x270f)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=ES, O=MOBILE-CA
        Validity
            Not Before: May  1 23:59:59 2013 GMT
            Not After : May  1 23:59:59 2023 GMT
        Subject: C=ES, CN=u020885-zzzzttttzzzz
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:f6:02:57:5e:af:ff:01:c8:8b:be:e7:ae:48:45:
                    94:be:c4:1e:ad:84:99:26:97:03:72:ef:03:11:4d:
                    7e:d8:ca:c1:c2:f5:2e:f9:c1:1f:c5:2d:61:5d:b2:
                    33:0f:fb:74:c4:96:fc:6c:72:4f:80:dd:e9:ac:77:
                    64:d8:70:9a:f4:b3:8a:7b:e6:f3:fc:93:70:9a:a7:
                    7f:66:4d:75:4d:2d:1c:9a:88:56:6d:e1:58:89:4d:
                    88:6c:35:6b:40:7d:2f:2d:f1:3e:7a:15:63:f1:cb:
                    5a:6b:8a:54:74:01:01:e9:f9:08:f9:54:a7:69:f1:
                    1c:1f:8a:4e:06:ac:73:86:59
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        a3:ee:50:a6:a5:9b:78:21:c7:a3:2b:21:f5:7c:bb:1e:10:01:
        c0:0a:84:7f:14:1f:2f:92:76:8b:2f:70:64:f1:7e:00:0c:e1:
        16:19:00:f7:64:be:53:75:06:11:2b:1a:6a:63:3e:3d:8f:62:
        2e:f7:4a:9c:61:f0:5e:2c:3f:d6:27:c6:f0:07:09:d6:6a:5d:
        67:d3:6a:45:64:95:8a:95:d9:58:8e:17:10:ed:9f:75:d0:0b:
        0f:da:81:b7:03:8b:6c:39:43:1a:51:2b:3e:02:5d:be:53:e6:
        0a:9f:4f:26:d3:d4:51:b9:b1:95:0e:ec:5b:a1:5b:5d:06:27:
        0a:fc
```

I extract the public key with

```
openssl x509 -in c/device.cer -noout -pubkey > c/device.pub.key.cer
```

and exactly matches that have javascript (var publickey)

Now comes the question. How do I make the same signature verification with OpenSSL on the server?

The file with the signature contains a hexadecimal number and tried

1 -. 
    openssl dgst -verify c/device.pub.key.cer -signature firma.sign message.txt

2 -. 
    openssl dgst -sha256 -verify c/device.pub.key.cer -signature firma.sign message.txt

3 -. 
    cat firma.sign | xxd -r -p > firma.s2 
    openssl dgst -verify c/device.pub.key.cer -signature firma.s2 message.txt

and other options, but the answer is always :

Verification Failure

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance and greetings.

Comment: You've just leaked your private key to the world. Change it now, and don't do that again.

Comment: This is a test private key.  I invite you to use that for something.

Comment: Is there any intelligent response?

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1. OpenSSL wants it's signature in binary format, not base64.  Use `| base64 -d` to decode it.
2. Your signature appears to be incorrect based on my tests.

Steps to create and validate a base64 signature based on your example:

1. Create our data input file:

   ```
   echo "zzzzttttzzzz" > zzzzttttzzzz.txt
   ```
2. When I sign the same message using `openssl`:

   ```
   openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem -out zzzzttttzzzz.signature zzzzttttzzzz.txt
   ```
3. But this signature is gobbledygook, so we should `base64` it to give a baseline against `jsrsasign`

   ```
   nÝ^@^Oú^P<...>
   ```
4. And then `base64` the signature:

   ```
   $ base64 zzzzttttzzzz.signature

   "bt0AD/oQxZ8EA0+J8HSFaQ4fYPEIj2+Nf1hUd87jHDb8vg/MUxKA/EccxQRCYXiVUg5GxBjj5J/W
   ZgHNmXZafl6azhC9kTUTS6zvd+TeOPwKFcOm5+g9Pf5ldOcoIpsqN3Fd1fwxrNPZqiawmWaJZHsX
   mwd00RC9xupK8BTiNrc="
   ```
5. To make sure we can decode and match the binary signature:

   ```
   echo "bt0AD/oQxZ8EA0+J8HSFaQ4fYPEIj2+Nf1hUd87jHDb8vg/MUxKA/EccxQRCYXiVUg5GxBjj5J/WZgHNmXZafl6azhC9kTUTS6zvd+TeOPwKFcOm5+g9Pf5ldOcoIpsqN3Fd1fwxrNPZqiawmWaJZHsXmwd00RC9xupK8BTiNrc=" | base64 -d | diff zzzzttttzzzz.signature -
   ```
6. And finally, verification:

   ```
   openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.key -signature zzzzttttzzzz.signature zzzzttttzzzz.txt

   "Verified OK"
   ```

**Summary**

- Fix the JavaScript signature generation and then convert it from base64 to binary and `openssl` should verify just fine.